# How to remove unwanted nested columns?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, kql, kusto-explorer, playfab

I've been tasked to alter the company's `Event Export` from our PlayFab Environment into Azure. Initially, we've set it up to `Export all events` but after looking at the data we do have some data exported that we don't want for legal reasons. I was exploring the `Use custom query` method and was trying to build the query to get all data except the columns I want to exclude. The problem is that these columns are nested. I've tried using the `project-away` query to exclude one column for now but when I run the below query

```sql
['events.all'] 
| project-away EventData.ColumnToExclude
| limit 100
```

I get this error

[image]

I'm assuming it's because it is not supporting nested columns. Is there an easy way to exclude the column without having to flatten the data or list all my columns (our developers might create new events without notice so that won't work)?

**UPDATE 1:**

I've found that `project-away` is the syntax to remove a column from a table but what I needed is a way to remove a key from a json/dynamic object so found that using `bag_remove_keys()` is the correct approach

```sql
['events.all']
| project EventData=bag_remove_keys(EventData, dynamic(['Key1', 'Key2', '$.Key3.SubKey1'])
```

But now I am facing another issue. When I use the `'$.'` notation for subkeys I get the below error

```
Query execution has resulted in error (0x8000FFFF): Partial query failure: Catastrophic failure (message: 'PropertyBagEncoder::Add: non-contiguous entries: ', details: '').
[0]Kusto.Data.Exceptions.KustoDataStreamException: Query execution has resulted in error (0x8000FFFF): Partial query failure: Catastrophic failure (message: 'PropertyBagEncoder::Add: non-contiguous entries: ', details: '').
Timestamp=2022-01-31T13:54:56.5237026Z
```

If I don't list any subkeys I don't get this issue and I can't understand why

**UPDATE 2:**

I found that `bag_remove_keys` has a bug. On the below query I get the described error in **UPDATE 1**

```sql
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
dynamic(
{
  "test1": "val",
  "test2": {},
  "test3": "val"
}
)
]
| extend d1=bag_remove_keys(d, dynamic(['$.SomeKey.Sub1', '$.SomeKey.Sub2']))
```

However, if I move the `"test2"` key at the end I don't get an error but `d1` will not show the `"test2"` key in the output.
[image]

Also, if I have a key in `bag_remove_keys()` that matches a key from the input like `| extend d1=bag_remove_keys(d, dynamic(['$.SomeKey.Sub1', '$.SomeKey.Sub2', 'test1']))` then, again it will not error but will remove `"test2"` from the output
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it Andrei, it is a bug and we are working on a fix.

Update - fix had been checked in and will be deployed within two weeks, please open a support ticket if you need it earlier.

Comment: wow, that was quick. Thanks for the support